# Two ImagePickerControllers in one View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

i have two imagepickers in my app. i have done the first correctly. user can choose from library or capture a photo and see it in the View. But when i try to copy codes and paste it and change action and object names, i have errors at two lines .

```
    -(IBAction)TakePhoto {

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

-(IBAction)ChooseExisting

{
    picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker2.delegate = self;
    [picker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

//the following part is the renamed part


-(IBAction)TakePhoto2 {

 picker3 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker3.delegate = self;
 [picker3 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
 [self presentViewController:picker3 animated:YES completion:NULL];

 }

 -(IBAction)ChooseExisting2

 {
 picker4 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker4.delegate = self;
 [picker4 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
 [self presentViewController:picker4 animated:YES completion:NULL];
  }
ERROR HERE !!-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker3 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{
    image2 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView2 setImage:image2];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
ERROR HERE !!!-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker3 {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

for both "(void)" s i get this error :  duplicate declaration of method ImagePickerControllerDidcancel and ImagePickerControllerdidFinishPickingMediaWithINfo

It would be great if you can fix the code for me. Thanks

thank you for any help and i'm sorry if my english is not good enough

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker3 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;

-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker3;
```

Above both are delegates of  `UIImagePickerController`.

They **must** exist only once in a controller class.

*Note: Changing the argument name(s) doesn't change the method declaration.*

Comment: You must use an if statement inside these methods to figure out which picker called it (`if(picker == self.picker1)`) or something like that.

Comment: can you be more specific i dont have enough development knowledge.